# Match and extract the ID of only those Date rows that have at least one value outside of a specified range

Tags: r, date, dplyr, subset, diff

I have a data frame that has a few `date` columns.

```
    Index Measurement       Date Measure.1     Date.1 Measure.2     Date.2 Measure.3     Date.3
1       1        56.0 2018-03-16         2 2018-03-23        12 2018-03-29      22.0 2018-04-05
2       2        56.0 2018-03-16        78 2018-03-23     41234 2018-03-29      12.0 2018-04-05
3      12        65.0       <NA>        54 2018-03-23        35       <NA>     323.0 2018-04-05
4      15       129.1 2018-03-16        78 2018-03-23        12 2018-03-29       2.0 2018-04-05
5      22        56.0 2018-03-16       786 2018-03-23       234 2018-03-29      21.0       <NA>
6     567          NA 2018-03-16        34 2018-03-23         4 2018-03-29     545.0 2018-04-21
7      75         5.0 2018-03-16        52 2018-03-23         3 2018-03-29       5.0 2018-04-05
8     563        12.0 2018-03-16        43 2018-03-23        34 2018-03-29       5.0 2018-04-05
9     436        12.0 2018-03-16         3 2018-03-23       123 2018-03-29     213.0 2018-04-05
10  34533        56.0 2018-03-16        43 2018-03-23        32 2018-03-29       5.0 2018-04-25
11 234234        76.0 2018-03-16       234 2018-03-31       324 2018-05-06       5.0 2018-04-05
12   6643        76.0 2018-03-16        23 2018-03-23       123 2018-03-29       0.2 2018-04-11
```

Here is the code to load my data (small sample):

```
structure(list(Index = c(1L, 2L, 12L, 15L, 22L, 567L, 75L, 563L, 
436L, 34533L, 234234L, 6643L), Measurement = c(56, 56, 65, 129.1, 
56, NA, 5, 12, 12, 56, 76, 76), Date = structure(c(17606, 17606, 
NA, 17606, 17606, 17606, 17606, 17606, 17606, 17606, 17606, 17606
), class = "Date"), Measure.1 = c(2L, 78L, 54L, 78L, 786L, 34L, 
52L, 43L, 3L, 43L, 234L, 23L), Date.1 = structure(c(17613, 17613, 
17613, 17613, 17613, 17613, 17613, 17613, 17613, 17613, 17621, 
17613), class = "Date"), Measure.2 = c(12L, 41234L, 35L, 12L, 
234L, 4L, 3L, 34L, 123L, 32L, 324L, 123L), Date.2 = structure(c(17619, 
17619, NA, 17619, 17619, 17619, 17619, 17619, 17619, 17619, 17657, 
17619), class = "Date"), Measure.3 = c(22, 12, 323, 2, 21, 545, 
5, 5, 213, 5, 5, 0.2), Date.3 = structure(c(17626, 17626, 17626, 
17626, NA, 17642, 17626, 17626, 17626, 17646, 17626, 17632), class = "Date")), .Names = c("Index", 
"Measurement", "Date", "Measure.1", "Date.1", "Measure.2", "Date.2", 
"Measure.3", "Date.3"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

I need to look **at the adjacent** `Date` columns in a **row-wise manner** and the difference between each adjacent date cell should **not be more than 9 days and not less than 3 days**.

I can achieve this in the following way:

```
diffdate_table <- df[ , grep( "Date" , names( df ) ) ] %>% rowwise() %>% diff.Date
```

The output of the code above will be:

```
> diffdate_table 
    Date.1  Date.2   Date.3
1   7 days  6 days   7 days
2   7 days  6 days   7 days
3  NA days NA days  NA days
4   7 days  6 days   7 days
5   7 days  6 days  NA days
6   7 days  6 days  23 days
7   7 days  6 days   7 days
8   7 days  6 days   7 days
9   7 days  6 days   7 days
10  7 days  6 days  27 days
11 15 days 36 days -31 days
12  7 days  6 days  13 days
```

**QUESTION**.

**How can I extract the `Index` (a column in the above dataset) of those rows that have at least one difference that is more than 9 days and less than 3 as calculated in diffdate_table?**

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, plus I'd never seen `diff.Date` before. Here's two `dplyr` ways to do it. Both get the same result, it's just a matter of whether you want to work with the data in long or wide shape to do the diffs.

The first version follows the way you set up, but I had to do a couple weird steps to make sure the index didn't get dropped. There might be a better way to do that.

The second `gather`s everything into a long shape from the beginning, uses `lag` and just a bare subtraction of dates.

Both then group by Index and count the number of differences with your criteria. Hope that helps!

```r
library(tidyverse)

diffs1 <- df %>%
    column_to_rownames("Index") %>%
    select_at(vars(starts_with("Date"))) %>%
    diff.Date() %>%
    rownames_to_column("Index") %>%
    mutate(Index = as.integer(Index)) %>%
    gather(key = date, value = diff, -Index) %>%
    filter(diff %>% between(3, 9)) %>%
    count(Index) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    arrange(Index)

diffs1
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>    Index     n
#>    <int> <int>
#>  1     1     3
#>  2     2     3
#>  3    15     3
#>  4    22     2
#>  5    75     3
#>  6   436     3
#>  7   563     3
#>  8   567     2
#>  9  6643     2
#> 10 34533     2

diffs1$Index
#>  [1]     1     2    15    22    75   436   563   567  6643 34533

diffs2 <- df %>%
    select_at(vars(Index, starts_with("Date"))) %>%
    gather(key = obs, value = date, -Index) %>%
    group_by(Index) %>%
    mutate(prev_date = lag(date)) %>%
    mutate(diff = date - prev_date) %>%
    filter(!is.na(diff)) %>%
    filter(diff %>% between(3, 9)) %>%
    summarise(n = n())
```

Created on 2018-04-25 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

**Edit**: Just realized you might not be interested in the counts of how many times each index had a diff in your range, only in the indexes that fit that criteria. In that case, you could just stop after `filter(diff %>% between(3, 9))` and take the unique indexes with `unique(diff1$Index)`.